# VBA - SQL update rows matching with columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm using MS Access and currently am using VBA and have 2 tables right now.  I am trying to insert/update rows in one table from the other.  The difference is one table has the data in row direction and the other in column direction, here's the first table (Table A) with first row as headers:

```
Item_Num  Cost  YearMonth
1         2     201101
2         5     201102
```

And here's how I would like this table updated (Table B) with first row as headers:

```
Item_Num  201101  201102  201103  201104  ...
1         2       2       2       2
2         1       5       5       5
```

In Table A, the YearMonth of 201101 is Cost of 2 for Item_Num 1.  So Table B would be updated for 201101 and on (to the last YearMonth column) for Item_Num 1 with a Cost of 2.

I've been able to update the first YearMonth it appears (201101 in the previous example), but can't seem to get the remaining columns.

Comment: What else does Table B contain besides a "historical" PIVOT of Table A? Why not create a Pivot Table Report/Query in Access to dynamically re-create Table B?

Comment: Well it has essentially all the same columns as Table A (Item_Num and a few other unique identifiers).  Do you mean a Pivot Table Report in Excel or is there a way in Access?

Comment: Look into Crosstab Queries in Access.

Comment: Oh yes, it's not exactly historical, it is actually being used for the future/forecast. I just used historical YearMonths in this example.  
For example, someone would update an Item in Table A with a cost of 2 at 201201. Then Table B would have a cost of 2 for that item for Columns 201201, 201202, and on.

Comment: Looking into crosstab queries, it's very helpful.  However users will usually not input a cost for every YearMonth, thus there are holes in the YearMonth columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I seem to have gotten it. I decided to create a temporary table that stored that values I wanted to update for Table B, it's a bit messy but it works.